# These words are for you alone

Tags: knowledge, cipher

Can you decode the message this tablet contains?

---

[image: Cipher]

---

Good luck!

Note: The [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge) tag is by no means necessary to solve this puzzle, but certain knowledge could be helpful in verifying the answer. Hints will be provided as necessary.

Comment: Some of the dots are filled in. Is this intended?

Comment: @RonchenLuo Yes, this is intentional.

Comment: @PDT A hint is coming soon for my last puzzle.

Comment: I feel that rot13(rnpu tebhc bs 3 qbgf vf bar flzoby, abg 3 flzobyf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Solving it as a simple substitution with many errors and/or assuming that some symbols substitute for *sounds* rather than letters as in a phonetic cipher produces this partial solution. Uncertain letters or sounds are in red.

> ```
> VESEL
> THOUGH BOHND YOU
> SHEL KNOW THE STETE OF
> THE WORLD
> HELOWNEST
> WIL BE WHOLE EGON
> ```

> [image]

> This suggests the phrase "world will be whole again" and a quick google search finds it is a [quote from Hollow Knight](https://hollowknight.fandom.com/wiki/Lore_Tablets_(Hollow_Knight)):
> *Vessel. Though bound, you shall know the state of the world. Hallownest will be whole again.*
> The puzzle's title, *these words are for you alone*, is also a Hollow Knight reference.

Comment: Congratulations! I might add another answer as a deeper explanation of the system.